# Obtain a formula of displayed height of an object in front of an Android's Phone Camera, given distance between the object and phone and real height.

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, derivation-of-formulae

Good day folks.

I have a bottle as an object with the real height ($h_{\text{real}}$) is $13$ cm and I put the bottle in front of my recording video phone with varied distances between them as in the table below. The object and the recording phone are both on the same flat plain wall surface.

After I put the bottle in each distance variation, I measure the height of the displayed bottle in the video recording application's screen using my ruler as the table below listed. We call this displayed height ($h_{\text{displayed}}$).

So, we now have $3$ variables, real height ($h_{\text{real}}$), displayed height ($h_{\text{displayed}}$) and distance ($d$).

My quest is to find a formula that relates those $3$ variables. Below is the data that I acquired using measurement in the format of a table.

| distance ($d$) | height of the displayed object ($h_{displayed}$) |
| --- | --- |
| $3$ cm | $4$ cm |
| $4$ cm | $3.3$ cm |
| $5$ cm | $2.3$ cm |
| $6$ cm | $2$ cm |
| $7$ cm | $1.6$ cm |
| $8$ cm | $1.4$ cm |
| $9$ cm | $1.3$ cm |
| $10$ cm | $1.1$ cm |
| $11$ cm | $1$ cm |
| $12$ cm | $0.9$ cm |
| $13$ cm | $0.8$ cm |
| $14$ cm | $0.7$ cm |

And below is the graph to help you guess or estimate what the function is close to what function. It is like or similar or close to exponential function tough. [image]

Thank you for your help.

Best regards,

Me

Comment: It seems that both the distance and the height of the object are something you can control, and not really dependent. What if you put an apple of $10$ cm tall at $10$ cm far? That data point would already mess up the pattern.

Comment: I am confused by your posting.  In particular, what does height represent exactly, with respect to the camera and the object?  Is the object of a fixed size and at a stationary point?  If so, how can the object's height ever change?

Comment: Sorry for this unclear description. Imagine a bottle as object with 13 cm tall (we call this real height or rh) stands at 10 cm (d) from the phone camera's and the camera is in video recording mode, I mean the phone is recording a video, the object will displayed by the recording apps at the screen of the camera. if we measure this displayed object on the screen height's with ruler, we call this displayed height (dh). So we have 3 variables, real height (rh), distance(d), and displayed height (dh) variables. How can I relate them together in a function formula?

Comment: I will revise my question above. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

To within the accuracy of the measurement it looks like the distance and display height are inversely proportional, where $d \cdot dh=11$. I didn't do a careful fit to get the $11$, just did it by eye off the data.  The $11$ should be proportional to the height of the object.  We can't be sure as you haven't tried different height objects.